# C++ passing istream the in conditional operator to the function

Tags: c++, stream, ternary-operator

I am quite confused about behaviour of conditional operator. Suppose function like this

```
SomeData read_from_stream(istream& stream);
```

The function itself is returning some data pack, we want to catch.

```
if (file_name != "")
    SomeData data = read_from_stream(ifstream(file_name)); // calling cpy/move constructor
else
    SomeData data = read_from_stream(cin);
// data out of scope :(
```

Ok then, put SomeData out of `if-else`

```
SomeData data; // calling default constructor :(
if (file_name != "")
    data = read_from_stream(ifstream(file_name));
else
    data = read_from_stream(cin);
```

Default constructor might not even exist. Ok then, another idea.

```
SomeData data = read_from_stream((file_name != "") ? ifstream(file_name) : cin);
```

> error C2248: 'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::basic_istream': cannot access protected member declared in class 'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'

Well, I've heard something about streams being not-copyable, but I am not copying anything, am I?

**EDIT:**

I came up with this

```
auto lmbd = [&file_name]() -> istream& {
    if (file_name != "")
        return ifstream(file_name); // returning reference to temporary :(
    else
        return cin;
};
SomeData data = read_from_stream(lmbd());
```

This compiles, but it crashes during run time when trying to `std::getline(stream, str);` if stream is ifstream set up using filename.

Comment: It's the "_conditional operator_". That it happens to be a ternary operator, and that it happens to be the only one, is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've heard something about streams being not-copyable, but I am not copying anything, am I?

Yeah, unfortunately, you are.

A conversion is performed from `std::ifstream` to `std::istream` before any reference binding occurs:

> `[C++11: 5.16/3]:` *[..]* **If `E2` is an rvalue** or if neither of the conversions above can be done **and at least one of the operands has (possibly cv-qualified) class type:**
>
> - **if `E1` and `E2` have class type, and** the underlying class types are the same or **one is a base class of the other: `E1` can be converted to match `E2` if the class of T2 is** the same type as, or **a base class of, the class of `T1`**, and the cv-qualification of `T2` is the same cv-qualification as, or a greater cv-qualification than, the cv-qualification of `T1`. **If the conversion is applied, `E1` is changed to a prvalue of type T2 by copy-initializing a temporary of type `T2` from `E1` and using that temporary as the converted operand.**
>
> *[..]*

There are all the standard ways to mitigate this (some of which you've already explored). A really nasty one that works is to add an overload to `read_from_stream` that takes an rvalue reference, and cast both expression operands to the same type:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

void f(std::istream&&);

int main()
{
    f(
        false
        ? (std::istream&&) std::ifstream("/tmp")
        : (std::istream&&) std::cin
    );
}
```

#### ([see it compiling](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/73261f0f611660ca))

As compared to my testcased version of your original code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

void f(std::istream&);

int main()
{
    f(
        false
        ? std::ifstream("/tmp")
        : std::cin
    );
}
```

(["`error: use of deleted function 'std::basic_istream<char>::basic_istream(const std::basic_istream<char>&)'`"](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db486415c539202f))

Comment: That's useful piece of information. May I ask you how would you solve this issue?

Comment: @Zereges, You could always just return a `std::istream &` from a function, or you could take it as a parameter to this function and bubble up the location it's set to a file stream or stdin.

Comment: @Zereges: I dunno it would depend on the application's coding style and what code is around this code.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I came up with another (non working) solution, see my edit.

Comment: @Zereges: If you captured `file_name` by value instead then it could work. I mean, except for the part where you return a reference to a temporary. What did you think of my solution above?

Comment: Sadly, your solution won't compile in Microsoft Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: @Zereges: Frankly, it's more sad that you're _using_ Microsoft Visual Studio 2015. :-)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I had to, for handling my homework which required variadic templates black magic which for some reason, was not compilable in compiler provided for Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, Why wouldn't I use something I am familiar with? But I thing we are off-topic and the discussion about unix VS microsoft is pointless just by definition.

Comment: @Zereges: How is it "pointless" when we're talking about a feature that your chosen compiler simply does not support? Why would you not consider switching to a standards-compliant compiler that can solve this problem and many others? That doesn't sound "pointless" to me.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: You called your "feature" `really nasty one that works`. I will rather redesign my code than use nasty things. And I do not need new compiler for this.

Comment: @Zereges: Haha, granted.